# Run the application on jail break iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.I am running the appliction in `xocde 4.4.1` and ios version is 4.1.And my iPhone is jailbreak iphone.So if I run my application then I am getting the error like  "**Xcode cannot run using the selected device**".So please tell me what are the changes I can do to run my application in this device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply jailbreaking your device does not allow you to build directly to the device via Xcode without proper provisioning. Xcode requires developer certificates (usually provided by Apple) in order to sign the application you are attempting to run on your device.

Jailbroken phones will not run unsigned code, but they will run code that has been signed by an untrusted source. This means you still need to be signing your application using a self-signed certificate. This requires generating a self-signed certificate in Keychain, then forcing Xcode to use self-signed certificates.

You then need to provision the device, and modify the build instructions for your application to use your self-signed certificate.

[Simple guide that should work with your version of Xcode.](http://gyolife.tumblr.com/post/11908836685/build-directly-to-jailbroken-device-xcode-4-2-5-0)

Comment: General guide to do this - [link](http://gyolife.tumblr.com/post/11908836685/build-directly-to-jailbroken-device-xcode-4-2-5-0)